# What happens internally in AWS when EC2 instance is upgraded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Wanted to know more about internals of AWS when we autoscale an instance from one tier to another. Does AWS creates an image and spins up new instance and restores the image ? or what exactly happens inside. ?

Comment: Are you talking about regular AWS Auto Scaling? It doesn't scale up (resize) an existing instance. It scales out (adds more instances of a pre-configured type that you specify). You can, however, stop an existing EBS–backed instance and restart it on a different instance type.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling will either **Launch** a new instance or **Terminate** an existing instance. This is known as **horizontal scaling**. No instance is "upgraded".

In fact, it is not possible to "upgrade" an Amazon EC2 instance. Instead, you need to **Stop** the instance, change the **Instance Type**, then **Start** the instance again. This will launch the instance on a different host, which is dedicated to running the new Instance Type.

The disks used on Amazon EC2 are (typically) **Amazon Elastic Block Store** (EBS) volumes. These are network-attached volumes that exist separately to the EC2 instance. Thus, the disks are preserved when the instance is stopped and they are automatically reattached to the instance when it is started again.